# tensorflow how to get the data type of a node using c api?

Tags: c, tensorflow

Suppose my graph have a node below:

```
node {
  name: "a"
  op: "Placeholder"
  attr {
    key: "dtype"
    value {
      type: DT_STRING
    }
  }
  attr {
    key: "shape"
    value {
      shape {
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and I want to get the data type of it (which is DT_STRING in this case).

I tried this:

```
TF_Operation *op = blahbalh;
TF_Status *status = TF_NewStatus();
TF_DataType type;
TF_OperationGetAttrType(op, "dtype", &type, status);
```

but the result of type is TF_ATTR_PLACEHOLDER.

and this:

```
TF_Input  input{op, 0};
auto type = TF_OperationInputType(input); 
// this gives: ./tensorflow/core/lib/gtl/inlined_vector.h:156] Check failed: i < size() (0 vs. 0)
```

Comment: Wait... `input{op, 0};`, `auto type = ... `? I don't think this is C, do you mean modern C++?

Comment: @raymai97 The important part is c. And I'm using the c api of tensorflow.

Comment: `TF_ATTR_PLACEHOLDER`  is of type `TF_AttrType` whereas `TF_STRING ` is of type `TF_DataType `. Coincidentally both have value `7`. I am guessing you have a bad typecast somewhere.

Comment: @TheMyth You're right. Thanks.